# Copied Mac OS Image, now I must boot into safe mode and reinstall OS on every restart

Tags: macos, mac, safe-mode

We copied one of our Mac Mini's hard drive images to another Mac Mini that we use as a build server for our iOS app. Every time we restart the new Mac that we copied the image to it doesn't start and we have to go into safe mode and reinstall the OS. Any idea what we can do to get around that. We have tried resetting the *NVRAM/PRAM*, verifying/repairing disk permission (which gives a lot of ACL found but not expected errors).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up running [ACLr8](https://github.com/fletom/ACLr8) and it fixed the issues. I enabled auto login, but I assume it is the first part as that should have no affect.